# how to update last access time of a remote (SMB) file

Tags: java, smb, jcifs, lastaccesstime

I want to update the last access time of a file sitting on a remote machine (samba) which I am accessing through java (jcifs).

How can I do it?

I am able to create a SmbFile object but not java.io.File object for  a remote file.

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.